# Passing value into an entity by direct string reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know it sounds a bit foggy so ill provide coded explanation.

Lets say I have an entity:

```
   public class Times
    {
        public int TimesId { get; set; }
        public int DateRange { get; set; }
        public String Days { get; set; }

    }
```

And an action with returned values.
I want to set a property inside of my entity according to the "name" value that have passed to the action:

```
public JsonResult SaveValues(string name, int value)
{
    //lets say: name = "TimesId" 

    times t = new times;
    // t.name = should refer to t.TimesId and used to insert values like t.TimesId
    t.name = value; // what I'm trying to acheive
}
```

Is it possible to do this kind of reference directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible, using reflection, by doing:

```
Times t = new Times();
typeof(Times).GetProperty(name).SetValue(t, value);
```

Realistically though, wouldn't you be better off just having your `SaveValues` taking a `Times` object as it's parameter? Then you can fill it yourself and save the reflection.

Comment: Because the real action receives serialized form string object which have to be stripped and splited first than pushed into the entity :-)

Comment: @JBntis If it receives the serialized form, then as long as your model in your view maps to the model in the action result, model binding will automatically wire that up for you.

Comment: -1 This will give compilation error. It should be like this. `typeof(Times).GetProperty(name).SetValue(t, value, null);`

Comment: @ewvfwrwwvw Incorrect, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291.aspx

Comment: I have rollback the downvote. Although, in 4.0 it has three parameter overload minimum. Please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx also

Comment: I have this script: http://jsfiddle.net/c7GQ8/ - running every time i click to next tab, this will run over all the input elements in the form and serialize them in the post in a linear string, how is it possible to map it with automatic binding?

Comment: @JBntis Just change your ajax method to do ` data: $("form").serialize(),` and make your action your posting to to take a model of the same type that your view has.

Comment: @mattytommo replacing to  data: $("form").serialize() won't pass anything.. The action being fired from a simple onclick event without anything else by the serializing js i've posted. How should I make the connection between that will "tell" the action to receive certain entity data from just the onclick?

Comment: @JBntis Ah, then you'll have to construct your own parameter list dynamically in that `click` function. Make sure the parameter names match the Model property names **exactly** and you'll still be able to keep the Model as the parameter on the action method.

Comment: Yea, The problem is that not all inputs have exact properties for the entity and need some modifications before inserted. Well thanks for the answer ill try it soon.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do this kind of reference directly?

Yes, you can use reflection:

```
typeof(times).GetProperty(name).SetValue(t, value)
```